# Add user metadata in Flutter

Tags: flutter, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to add raw_user_metadata on the auth.users table when a new user creates an account. However, I'm unable to find the documentation for how to do so in Flutter. The documentation exists for  the Javascript client library so it seems to be possible, but it isn't documented for Flutter.

See the "sign up with additional user metatdata" javascript documentation here: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup

In javascript, this is how you add raw_user_metadata:

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp(
  {
    email: 'example@email.com',
    password: 'example-password',
    options: {
      data: {
        first_name: 'John',
        age: 27,
      }
    }
  }
)
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```dart
final AuthResponse res = await supabase.auth.signUp(
  email: 'example@email.com',
  password: 'example-password',
  data: {'username': 'my_user_name'},
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the [Supabase Flutter related docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/auth-signup) itself:

```
 final AuthResponse res = await supabase.auth.signUp(
    email: 'example@email.com',
    password: 'example-password',
 );
 final Session? session = res.session;
 final User? user = res.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` param on `signup()` is a `Map<String, dynamic>?`. So you can try this:

```
Future<AuthResponse?> signup(
  String fname, 
  String lname, 
  String gender, 
  String bdate, 
  String email, 
  String password,
) async {

  final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    'first_name': fname,
    'last_name': lname,
    'gender': gender,
    'birthdate': bdate
  };

  return supabase.auth.signUp(
    password: password,
    email: email,
    data: data,
  );
}
```